# MySQL INDEX() syntax equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing, syntax

I am following a PHP workbook and one of the exercises asks me to create a table with columns using the following MySQL code

```
CREATE TABLE messages ( 
    message_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    forum_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    subject VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    body LONGTEXT NOT NULL, 
    date_entered DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id), 
    INDEX (parent_id), 
    INDEX (forum_id),
    INDEX (user_id),
    INDEX (date_entered) 
);
```

The problem is at the place I work they use Microsoft SQL Server so the syntax is different.

What is the equivalent SQL Server syntax I can use for

```
INDEX (parent_id), 
INDEX (forum_id),
INDEX (user_id),
INDEX (date_entered)
```

Comment: you have error? show the exact error message

Comment: Yes I get `Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.`

Comment: You have encountered the tip of the iceberg when it comes to inconsistencies between RDBMS vendors.

Answer (score 1):

What is the equivalent SQL Server syntax I can use for

```
 INDEX (parent_id), 
 INDEX (forum_id),
 INDEX (user_id),
 INDEX (date_entered)
```

Looking in the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) i notice the BNF form.

```
<column_index> ::=   
 INDEX index_name [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]  
    [ WITH ( <index_option> [ ,... n ] ) ]  
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name (column_name )   
         | filegroup_name  
         | default   
         }  
    ]   
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { filestream_filegroup_name | partition_scheme_name | "NULL" } ]
```

So SQL Server 2008+ should also support `INDEX` keyword in the `CREATE TABLE` statement..

But the valid syntax for the `INDEX` keyword is using

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
   id INT
 , INDEX index_name (id)
);
```

But there are other things wrong like datatypes or keywords..

The correct SQL code for SQL server is

```
CREATE TABLE messages ( 
 message_id INT identity(1, 1), 
 parent_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 forum_id TINYINT NOT NULL, 
 user_id INT NOT NULL, 
 subject VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 body TEXT NOT NULL, 
 date_entered DATETIME NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (message_id), 
 INDEX parent_id (parent_id), 
 INDEX forum_id (forum_id),
 INDEX user_id (user_id),
 INDEX date_entered (date_entered) 
);
```

Comment: still needs an `identity` for the `message_id`

Comment: "still needs an identity for the message_id" indeed @JoelCoehoorn thanks forget that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use syntax that should work in any SQL engine, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE messages ( 
    message_id INT, 
    parent_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    forum_id TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    user_id INT NOT NULL, 
    subject VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL, 
    date_entered DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
)
```

Then create other indexes individually:

```
CREATE INDEX parent_id_idx ON messages (parent_id))
```

And so on.

This syntax should be supported by all SQL engines.